# parsing jsonpath in php

Tags: php, json

I've a Json structure :

```html
{
   "Photos":{
        "Photo":[
              {
                "ID" :111,
                "URL": "blabla"
                
              },
              {
                 "ID":222
                 "URL" "blaaaaaaaaa"
              }
                ]
            }
}
```

i want to insert a kind of "sub-data" in photo identified by 222
such that final output will be :

```html
{
   "Photos":{
        "Photo":[
              {
                "ID" :111,
                "URL": "blabla"
                
              },
              {
                 "ID":222 {"CROP": 5x7, "Pixel":"none"}
                 "URL" "blaaaaaaaaa"
              }
                ]
            }
}
```

i came across a php coded-json path evaluator 
(authored by by stefan Goessner : http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath)
that enables xpath-like operations on json structures. then, i used it as follows:

```html
require_once('json.php');           //the parser location file
require_once('jsonpath.php');

$parser = new Services_JSON(SERVICE_JSON_LOOSE_TYPE);
$jobj = $parser->decode(file_get_contents("filename.json", true));
$result = jsonPath($jobj, "$.Photos.Photo..ID");
if($result != false){
    $result[0] = array("CROP" => 5x7, "Pixel" => "none");
}


file_put_contents("filename.json", $parser->encode($jobj));   // white back correction
```

why's this not working ? any help will be appreciated as i am new to this whole
world of jsonpath thanks !

Comment: Can you post whatever error, or unexpected result you get?

Comment: Why would you not json_decode the string, modify your associative array and then json_encode it again ? This would be much simpler and work with native php functions.

Answer (score 0):

this would be your json well parsed:

```
{
    "Photos":{
        "Photo":[
            {
                "ID" : 111,
                "URL": "blabla"  
            },
            {
                "ID": 222,
                "sub-data": {"CROP": "5x7", "Pixel": "none"},
                "URL": "blaaaaaaaaa"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: @Reti43, no error displayed in actuality, but the expected result was not written to file as expected. lorenz mayer, ur right. but i hate doing stuff like finding xml or json(my new hobby) data with loops. i just wanna take full advantage of the regex functionality. Octal, thanks for the observation. so guys, wats the way out?